# Scala 3: Define a typeclass instance for an inner class

Tags: scala, typeclass, scala-3

I am trying to define typeclass instances for an inner class.

As a minimal example, I have code that looks like this:

```scala
trait Typeclass[T]

class Outer:

  class Inner
```

I would like to define an instance of `Typeclass` for `Inner`, so that this compiles:

```scala
object Main:

  import Instances.given

  val outer = new Outer
  val x = summon[Typeclass[outer.Inner]]
```

It should be possible for the instance to depend on the value of `Outer`.

I would prefer the instance to reside in a different file (possibly a different package) from both `Typeclass` and `Outer`. In this case, defining a given instance inside `Outer` is not an option.

Is it possible to achieve this in Scala 3?

Below I will outline what I have tried:

#### Attempt 1: Parameterisation on `Outer`

```scala
object Instances:

  given instance(using outer: Outer): Typeclass[outer.Inner] =
    new Typeclass { }
```

This kind of works, but unfortunately the `using` clause requires that the value of `Outer` be marked as given.

#### Attempt 2: Type projection

```scala
object Instances:

  given instance: Typeclass[Outer#Inner] =
    new Typeclass { }
```

This doesn't work at all. The compiler refuses to use `instance`. Also, even if it did work, it wouldn't allow `instance` to depend on the value of `Outer`.

#### Attempt 3: Extension method

```scala
object Instances:

  extension (outer: Outer)
    given instance: Typeclass[outer.Inner] =
      new Typeclass { }
```

It seems extension givens aren't even syntactically valid in Scala 3. (I suspect for good reason!)

Comment: Does something like this work for your use case? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/1nV8GwdlTo2CUkBXRJijdg/12

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez This is pretty good. However, the `outer.context` might be a bit too clunky. Is there a way to do this where the user can do something like `import outer.given` instead, while still keeping the instance definition outside of the class? That'd still be less than ideal but might be the best that can be done.

Comment: Yes you can do that: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/1nV8GwdlTo2CUkBXRJijdg/13 I tried to provide a way with automatic derivation but the compiler couldn't figure out the types: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/1nV8GwdlTo2CUkBXRJijdg/5 I would say this is a bug worth reporting.